# Go back to dependent CRUD after adding, editing, deleting and canceling

Tags: zend-framework2

I have districts depends on provinces, i.e., for every province I have different districts. e.g.,
[image]

[image]

When I click on Add new District, following page is opened:
[image]

Problem is that after clicking Cancel or Adding district: Main page is come, without Districts (which is necessary) as:

[image]

Similar is the case in Edit and Delete.
I tried a solution for it: Id of selected province should be passed along with id of districts (to be edited/deleted). In case of Add, it works fine because only one id is passed. But in case of edit/delete, it don’t work because ids of province and districts cannot passed both in

```
<a href="<?php echo $this->url('districts', 
                    array('action'=>'edit', 'id' => $districts->id));?>">Edit</a>  
<a href="<?php echo $this->url('districts',
                    array('action'=>'delete', 'id' => $districts->id));?>">Delete</a>
```

module.config.php:

```
<?php 

namespace Admin;

return array(
'router' => array(
    'routes' => array( 

        'profile' => array(
            'type' => 'Segment',
            'may_terminate' => true,
            'options' => array(
                'route' => '/profile[/:action][/:id]',
                'constraints' => array(
                    'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                    'id'     => '[0-9]+',
                ),
                'defaults' => array(
                    'controller' => 'Admin\Controller\Profile',
                    'action' => 'index',
                ),
            ),
        ),

        'provinces' => array(
            'type' => 'Segment',
            'may_terminate' => true,
            'options' => array( 
                'route' => '/provinces[/:action][/:id]', 
                'constraints' => array(
                    'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                    'id'     => '[0-9]+',
                ),
                'defaults' => array(
                    'controller' => 'Admin\Controller\Provinces',
                    'action' => 'index',
                ),
            ),
        ),

        'districts' => array(
            'type' => 'Segment',
            'may_terminate' => true,
            'options' => array(
                'route' => '/districts[/:action][/:id]',
                'constraints' => array(
                    'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                    'id'     => '[0-9]+',
                ),
                'defaults' => array(
                    'controller' => 'Admin\Controller\Districts',
                    'action' => 'index',
                ),
            ),
        ),



        'home' => array(
            'type'    => 'Literal',
            'options' => array(
                'route'    => '/admin',
                'defaults' => array(
                    '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Admin\Controller',
                    'controller'    => 'Index',
                    'action'        => 'index',
                ),
            ),
            'may_terminate' => true,
            'child_routes' => array(
                'default' => array(
                    'type'    => 'Segment',
                    'options' => array(
                        'route'    => '/[:controller[/:action]]',
                        'constraints' => array(
                            'controller' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                            'action'     => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                        ),
                        'defaults' => array(
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),

    ),
),
'service_manager' => array(
    'abstract_factories' => array(
        'Zend\Cache\Service\StorageCacheAbstractServiceFactory',
        'Zend\Log\LoggerAbstractServiceFactory',
    ),
    'factories' => array(
        'translator' => 'Zend\Mvc\Service\TranslatorServiceFactory',
        'navigation_admin' => 'Zend\Navigation\Service\DefaultNavigationFactory', 
    ),
),
'translator' => array(
    'locale' => 'en_US',
    'translation_file_patterns' => array(
        array(
            'type'     => 'gettext',
            'base_dir' => __DIR__ . '/../language',
            'pattern'  => '%s.mo',
        ),
    ),
),
'controllers' => array(
    'invokables' => array( 

        'Admin\Controller\Index' => 'Admin\Controller\IndexController',
        'Admin\Controller\Profile' => 'Admin\Controller\ProfileController',

        'Admin\Controller\Provinces' => 'Admin\Controller\ProvincesController',
        'Admin\Controller\Districts' => 'Admin\Controller\DistrictsController',

    ),
),
'view_manager' => array(
    'display_not_found_reason' => true,
    'display_exceptions'       => true,
    'doctype'                  => 'HTML5',
    'not_found_template'       => 'error/404',
    'exception_template'       => 'error/index',
    'template_map' => array(


        'layout/layout_admin'           => __DIR__ . '/../view/layout/layout.phtml',
        'admin/index/index' => __DIR__ . '/../view/admin/index/index.phtml',
        'error/404'               => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/404.phtml',
        'error/index'             => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/index.phtml',
    ),
    'template_path_stack' => array(
        __DIR__ . '/../view',
    ),

    /*
    'strategies' => array(
        'ViewJsonStrategy',
    ), 
    */
),

// Placeholder for console routes
'console' => array(
    'router' => array(
        'routes' => array(
        ),
    ),
),

'navigation_admin' => array(
    'default' => array(
        array(
            'label' => 'Home',
            'route' => 'home',
        ),

        array(
            'label' => 'Profile',
            'route' => 'profile',
            'pages' => array( 
                array(
                    'label' => 'Edit',
                    'route' => 'profile',
                    'action' => 'edit',
                ), 
                array(
                    'label' => 'Change Password',
                    'route' => 'profile',
                    'action' => 'changepassword',
                ), 
            ),
        ),

        array(
            'label' => 'Provinces',
            'route' => 'provinces',
            'pages' => array(
                array(
                    'label' => 'Add',
                    'route' => 'provinces',
                    'action' => 'add',
                ),
                array(
                    'label' => 'Edit',
                    'route' => 'provinces',
                    'action' => 'edit',
                ),
                array(
                    'label' => 'Delete',
                    'route' => 'provinces',
                    'action' => 'delete',
                ),
            ),

        ),


        array(
            'label' => 'Districts',
            'route' => 'districts',

            'pages' => array(
                array(
                    'label' => 'Add',
                    'route' => 'districts',
                    'action' => 'add',
                ),
                array(
                    'label' => 'Edit',
                    'route' => 'districts',
                    'action' => 'edit',
                ),
                array(
                    'label' => 'Delete',
                    'route' => 'districts',
                    'action' => 'delete',
                ),
            ),

        ),



    ),  
),
);
```

This issue is arise because that districts are dependent in province in this case. Without dependency in province every thing is fine.

So how could I solve this issue? Please give me some guidance or suggestion so that I continued my work.

Comment: Can you please paste your '_MODULE_/config/module.config.php' file here. You should replace the  '_MODULE_' text with the module name where you have put your controller and view.

Answer (score 1):

The 'districts' route is only set to take 'id', please change the config to below.

```
        'districts' => array(
            'type' => 'Segment',
            'may_terminate' => true,
            'options' => array(
                'route' => '/districts[/:action][/:id][/province_id/:province_id]',
//or
//'route' => '/districts[/:action][/:id][/:province_id]',
                'constraints' => array(
                    'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                    'id'     => '[0-9]+',
                ),
                'defaults' => array(
                    'controller' => 'Admin\Controller\Districts',
                    'action' => 'index',
                ),
            ),
        ),
```

and change the url to

```
<a href="<?php echo $this->url('districts', 
                    array('action'=>'edit', 'id' => $districts->id,'province_id'=>$provinceId));?>">Edit</a>
```

You should have the 'province_id' parameter in the 'action' now for you to manipulate 'view'.